# maximum length of string in db assembly

Tags: assembly

I see other that store all string in a byte
just like below

```
msg db  'Hello, world!',0xa
```

what's the maximum length of the string would be in a byte?

Comment: Probably at least 2^32 bytes, depending on the assembler.  Writing a program that can usefully do anything with a string that large is another matter, especially if you're writing 32 or 16-bit code, not x86-64 code.  (Is this x86 at all?  Some non-x86 assemblers use `db`, I think.)

Comment: _"store all string in a byte"_ It's not **a** byte, if that's what your question was about. It's one _or more_ bytes. Writing `db 'Hi!'` is effectively the same as writing `db 'H','i','!'` (i.e. 3 bytes in this case).

Comment: @Michael thank you so much bro

Comment: The resulting machine code doesn't know "string", so the assembler must somehow break this source definition to basic elements which exist in binary machine code and that's bytes (and bits). Most of the assemblers support "listing" option which usually does produce text variant of original source, but with produced machine code bytes included next to the source, which makes it easy to see in this particular case, how the "string" is broken down into separate bytes (depending on the source and assembler encoding, one char may be exactly one byte (ASCII), or more). Then memory limits do apply.

Comment: I.e. lot of the "string" manipulation depends on your particular assembler and environment, which bytes exactly are produced by such definition. But once you are in the land of bytes, the maximum length of everything depends on the target binary format and available memory on the system (i.e. if you are producing ROM image to be burnt into EEPROM, the less careful environment tools may let you build even too large image, which will get silently truncated upon writing it into the chip, more clever tools will keep an eye and emit some warnings when certain boundaries are crossed)